# Disable certain buttons javascript when id's are different

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to disable a certain group of buttons at a specific time. Using this js:

```
document.getElementById("reset").setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
```

But all IDs are different, the buttons is like `<button id=1> <button id=2>` etc. Can I set some made up variable like `<button group="hello">`

And then do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("group:hello").setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
```

to disable all of the buttons, even though the ID attribute is different from button to button?

Comment: You can give the elements class names and then use `getElementsByClassName()` to retrieve them. That returns a list of elements, and you would iterate over the list and set the attribute on each one separately.

Comment: With jQuery, that's a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is use the data attribute, see next:

```
<button  data-group="hello" id="button1">test1</button>
<button  data-group="hello" id="button2">test2</button>
<button  data-group="hello" id="button3">test3</button>
```

and the JS

```
 document.querySelectorAll('[data-group="hello"]').forEach(function(button) {
      button.disabled = true;
});
```

edit, here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xycmj4gv/2/

Comment: You could chain forEach to querySelectorAll, without creating buttonList variable.

Comment: @Kirill I am not sure but i guess forEach have compatibility issue in some browser. I may be wrong.

Comment: @Zicsus IE9+ same as querySelectorAll: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of ID.
Code is easy:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("group1").setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: This only gives you the first element

Comment: Didn't work. Only one of all buttons disables even though they have the same class

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged jquery

```
$(".mybutton").attr("disabled", true);
```

Where mybutton is

```
<button class= "mybutton"> </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `class` instead of `id` as follows:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("{yourClassName}");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    elements[i].setAttribute(“disabled”, “red");
}

<button class="{yourClassName}”></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getElementsByTagName` to get all buttons and then You can use `Array.Prototype.forEach` to disable all buttons like below. `forEach` will loop through all element and add desired attribute(in your case disabled) to all found elements.

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call
(document.getElementsByTagName("button"), function(e) {
      e.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
 });
```

```html
<button id="1">12</button> <button id="2">12</button>
<button id="3">12</button> <button id="4">12</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards for Id's:

Starts-with selector

```
document.querySelector("[id^=myId]")
```

works for

```
id="myId1"
id="myId2"
...
```

or Ends-with selector

```
document.querySelector("[id$=myId]")
```

works for

```
id="firstMyId"
id="secondMyId",...
```

Hint:
Please don't start Id's with numbers like: id="1myId". That's not w3c conform

Answer (score 0):

use class to group buttons, like this:

```
var btnsGroup = document.getElementsByClassName('group');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(btnsGroup, function(button) {
  button.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this-

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("[reset='true']");

for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) 
{
    buttons[i].setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
}
```

And HTML goes like this-

```
<button reset="true" >1 Candy</button>
<button reset="true" >2 Candy</button>
```

Comment: querySelectorAll has same browser support as forEach, so you might as well use it instead of for loop. Otherwise worth using one of the older DOM navigation functions for better browser support.
https://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector
https://caniuse.com/#feat=es5

Comment: @Kirill Yeah, I am doing it like this because of browser support.